# MVVM: Which component is in charge of navigation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-phone-7, mvvm

I am working on a Windows Phone 7 application. Now I need to switch the view after a user tapped the designated button which takes user to another view.

Which component, theoretically, in MVVM should be in charge of the navigation, i.e. switching views? Code snippets would be good to show demonstration.

I have tried inserting the switching code in View and it works alright, but I encountered a situation where I call an asynchronous web service and would like to navigate user to the new view only after the operation is done, the navigation code should be inside the event handler.

Thank you.

P/S: My project's deadline is coming soon, I have no time to rebuild my project using MVVM tools, such as MVVM Light, Caliburn Micro, and etc.

Comment: Regarding your PS: do you have the time to make a framework yourself?

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd No, I don't. In the end, I just wired everything up and make sure they work. I will try to learn one of the frameworks available, probably Prism.

Answer (score 2):

I put a Navigate methods in the base class that all my ViewModel's share:

```
protected void Navigate(string address)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(address))
        return;

    Uri uri = new Uri(address, UriKind.Relative);
    Debug.Assert(App.Current.RootVisual is PhoneApplicationFrame);
    BeginInvoke(() =>
        ((PhoneApplicationFrame)App.Current.RootVisual).Navigate(uri));
}

protected void Navigate(string page, AppViewModel vm)
{
    // this little bit adds the viewmodel to a static dictionary
    // and then a reference to the key to the new page so that pages can
    // be bound to arbitrary viewmodels based on runtime logic
    string key = vm.GetHashCode().ToString();
    ViewModelLocator.ViewModels[key] = vm;

    Navigate(string.Format("{0}?vm={1}", page, key));
}

protected void GoBack()
{
    var frame = (PhoneApplicationFrame)App.Current.RootVisual;
    if (frame.CanGoBack)
        frame.GoBack();
}
```

So the ViewModel base class executes the navigation if that's what you are asking. And then typically some derived ViewModel class controls the target of the navigation in response to the execution of an ICommand bound to a button or hyperlink in the View.

```
protected SelectableItemViewModel(T item)
{
    Item = item;
    SelectItemCommand = new RelayCommand(SelectItem);
}

public T Item { get; private set; }

public RelayCommand SelectItemCommand { get; private set; }

protected override void SelectItem()
{
    base.SelectItem();
    Navigate(Item.DetailPageName, Item);
}
```

So the View only knows when a navigate action is needed and the ViewModels know where to go (based on ViewModel and Model state) and how to get there.

Comment: +1 because I think the GoBack() is something I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The view should have a limited number of possible destinations. If you have to have a top-level navigation on every page, that should be part of your layout or you can put them in a child view.

Answer (score 0):

I put navigation outside of MVVM in a class that is responsible for showing/hiding views.

The ViewModels use a messagebroker with weakevents to publish messages to this class.

This setup gives me most freedom and doesn't put any responsibilities in the MVVM classes that do not belong there.